# Problema con posición de texto

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema con el texto que va arriba de la imagen, necesito que el texto no pase por arriba del `header` y que solo se quede en la foto (*que el texto pase por abajo del header y no por arriba*).

También hay un error para la versión movil (*si lo prueban reduciendo el navegador*) es que aparece "tienda" al lado del menú desplegable, no quiero que se vea "tienda" en la versión movil ya que quedaría raro al ya tener el menú desplegable.

Intente muchas veces resolverlo pero no lo he logrado resolver.
((Correccion de informacion sencible))

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
 background: #1E1E1E;
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
.fa-2x a{
  float: right;
}
 .centered {
  color:white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Company name</a>
 <div class="fa-2x">
  <a class="shopy" href="shop.html">Tienda</a></div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
<div>
 <img src="" width="100%">
</div>
 <div class="centered"><h1>Company name</h1></div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: deseo eliminar la pregunta ya que podriera afectar a mi empreza y no considero que sea de ayuda a alguien mas

Comment: Brian, las preguntas no se pueden eliminar si ya tienen una respuesta. Se ha editado toda referencia al nombre de la empresa, con eso debería bastar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considera aplicar los cambios del siguiente modo

- El texto **TIENDA** lo envolvería en un `span` para que de este modo no rompa tu maquetación y lo podamos mover

Código:

```
<span>Tienda</span>
```

- Al `span` del paso anterior **lo modificamos a nivel de la *media query*** indicando que tenga un `display: none;`

Código:

```
.shopy span{
  display: none;
}
```

- Ahora el icono del menú de hamburguesa quedará un poco lejos de la orilla, para evitar esto, lo podemos mover con `margin-right` 60px a la derecha de este modo:

Código:

```
.fa {
  margin-right: -60px;
}
```

- Finalmente para evitar que cuando haces *scroll* el título pase por arriba del encabezado del menú, alcanza con que a la clase `.topnav` le pongas un `z-index` de 1 así:

Código

```
.topnav{
  // ... tus estilos
  z-index: 1;
}
```